# Trigger Sagemaker Inference from SQS event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sagemaker

I have previously created Sagemaker Inference end-point and triggered from with API Gateway, but how can I trigger it from SQS event.

Usecase is: We are getting events in SQS, and whenever we get an event in SQS, we need to run the model.

Comment: You'll probably need to subscribe an AWS Lambda function to the Amazon SQS queue, and then code the Lambda function to trigger SageMaker.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein that's what i also thought, just wanted to check if we can trigger it directly somehow. lambda will increase the cost right?

Answer (score 0):

If your Endpoint is a realtime endpoint,
in order to make the `InvokeEndpoint` API call you would need use say a Lambda  function as a trigger. In terms of Lambda pricing please see the pricing doc [here](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)